# convert monthly data into quarter by unique column values in R

Tags: r

here is my dataframe
3 categories of data are under the LFS column :  Unemployment and Labour force
And the data are also different for different NAICS.

FOR each NAICS, I need to convert the monthly data into quarterly data (average the 3 months data) for each (Unemployment, Labour force) by NAICS, there are other columns in the dataframe, such as GeoUID does not need ot be aggregated.  Only need to aggregate the VALUE column.

After the quarterly data table is created, instead of Q1-yyyy format, can it be displayed as 2015-03-01.
Then a third data called UR can then be calculate (unemployment rate = unemployment divide by labour force).

Right now, I do this by exporting the subset table by LFS, but there should be amore efficient way of doing it?

| DATE | GeoUID | Industry | LFS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Unemployment | 200 |
| 2015-02-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Unemployment | 200 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Unemployment | 200 |
| 2015-01-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Labour force | 500 |
| 2015-02-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Labour force | 500 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Labour force | 500 |
| 2015-01-01 | 35 | Construction | Unemployment | 300 |
| 2015-02-01 | 35 | Construction | Unemployment | 300 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Construction | Unemployment | 300 |
| 2015-01-01 | 35 | Construction | Labour force | 800 |
| 2015-02-01 | 35 | Construction | Labour force | 800 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Construction | Labour force | 800 |

My results new table should look like this

| DATE | GeoUID | Industry | LFS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Unemployment | 200 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Labour force | 500 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Agriculture | Unmeployment rate | 0.4 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Construction | Unemployment | 300 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Construction | Labour force | 800 |
| 2015-03-01 | 35 | Construction | Unmeployment rate | 0.375 |

Btw here is my code which is also not working...
(newdf<-unemp%>%
group_by(Industry, quarter = quarters(REF_DATE), year = lubridate::year(REF_DATE)) %>%
summarise(mean_var = mean(VALUE)))

Comment: You can **Edit** your original post to include the code, rather than putting it in the comments.  Use code fences (```) to display code `like this`.

Comment: Please add your data to the question using `dput(newdf)` it makes life simpler to copy data to test and verify potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
newdf <- unemp %>%
  group_by(DATE = lubridate::floor_date(DATE, "quarter") + months(2),
           GeoUID,
           Industry,
           LFS) %>%
  summarise(VALUE = mean(VALUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = LFS, values_from = VALUE) %>% 
  mutate("Unemployment rate" = Unemployment / `Labour force`) %>% 
  pivot_longer(`Labour force`:`Unemployment rate`)
newdf
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 5
> # Groups:   DATE, GeoUID, Industry [2]
>   DATE       GeoUID Industry     name                value
>   <date>      <dbl> <chr>        <chr>               <dbl>
> 1 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Labour force      500    
> 2 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Unemployment      200    
> 3 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Unemployment rate   0.4  
> 4 2015-03-01     35 Construction Labour force      800    
> 5 2015-03-01     35 Construction Unemployment      300    
> 6 2015-03-01     35 Construction Unemployment rate   0.375
> ```

Some remarks

1. The OP has requested that the quarter should be denoted by an object of class `Date`. Furthermore, the OP has asked to align the dates of the first quarter with the 1st of March. So, the data are grouped by the first day of each quarter plus 2 months.
2. `GeoUID` is also considered as a grouping variable. Otherwise, it must not appear in the final result.
3. For computing  `Unemployment rate`, the data is being reshaped forth and back. Presumably, there are other, more efficient approaches where the data need not to be reshaped.

#### EDIT: Version without reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
df_quarter <- unemp %>%
  group_by(DATE = lubridate::floor_date(DATE, "quarter") + months(2),
           GeoUID,
           Industry,
           LFS) %>%
  summarise(VALUE = mean(VALUE))
newdf <- bind_rows(
  df_quarter,  
  df_quarter %>% 
    summarise(VALUE = VALUE[LFS == "Unemployment"] / VALUE[LFS == "Labour force"], 
              LFS = "Unemployment rate")
) %>% 
  arrange(DATE, GeoUID, Industry)
newdf
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 5
> # Groups:   DATE, GeoUID, Industry [2]
>   DATE       GeoUID Industry     LFS                 VALUE
>   <date>      <dbl> <chr>        <chr>               <dbl>
> 1 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Labour force      500    
> 2 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Unemployment      200    
> 3 2015-03-01     35 Agriculture  Unemployment rate   0.4  
> 4 2015-03-01     35 Construction Labour force      800    
> 5 2015-03-01     35 Construction Unemployment      300    
> 6 2015-03-01     35 Construction Unemployment rate   0.375
> ```